# Understanding basic for-each loops java

Tags: java

In java, I know that on this site, topics such as `for-each` or enhanced `for` loops have been covered before, but I don't still really get how they work.

For example,

```
String[] a = { "A", "B", "C", "D" }; 
String b = ""; 

for (String q : a) 
    b = q + b; 

System.out.println(b);
```

What would `b` output? 
Could you tell me how this is so? 
Thank you.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: No this is just an example I came up with. I dont get how I could logically solve this in my mind or "single-step" it in my mind.

Comment: Why not try compiling and running it?

Comment: ok but I would not know how it reached that point which is what I want to know

Comment: Start with replace the b = q + b by print q. It is basically saying:  for all the elements in the array q, display it on the screen. Now that you understand that you are going to go over each element of your array, think about what the addition does for strings? It will append the string element to the beginning of the b string. You start with an empty string, you get the element "A", you add it, you have "A". You do the same with "B", you get "BA"...and so on

Comment: Damn it, I didnt realize it would be printed backwards because of what comes first. Thank you Jeremy...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It doesn't show a basic understanding of the problem being asked.

Answer (score 0):

the output would be "DCBA"

a for each loop is like standard for loop with the convenience of an assignment to a loop scope variable

What you wrote is equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    String q = a[i];
    b = q + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Output would be "DCBA".

In every loop q is one element of your Array.  And you add it one after another to the front of b.

Answer (score 0):

b would output "DCBA".

In your loop, you're traversing through each string element in the array a. Since you set:

```
b = q + b
```

Instead of:

```
b = b + q
```

, each new element you traverse though is being added **before** what was contained in b previously, causing you to add each letter in the array backwards. (If you had the latter assignment, you would have had "ABCD").